# Clear output line in terminal after use for countdown (different length strings)

Tags: python, datetime, console, timer

The method to overwrite the same line is well known and I use it for countdown, but what about when the next output string has a different size and will be generated by a single print? That's the reason for my question!

I use a text countdown timer like (all on the same line):

```
Next activation in  5 seconds
Next activation in  4 seconds
Next activation in  3 seconds
Next activation in  2 seconds
Next activation in  1 seconds
```

In order not to waste unnecessary lines, I created a false way to produce the same result as the keyboard backspace button (false because it actually only writes over the top with blank spaces, giving the false impression that we return to the first position left writing in the terminal):

```
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    while True:
        print('-------- test --------')

        print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%d/%m %H:%M'))

        for remaining in range(5, 0, -1):
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            txt_value = f'Next activation in {remaining:2d} seconds'
            sys.stdout.write(txt_value)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + len(txt_value)*' ')
        sys.stdout.write('\r')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output countdown:

```
-------- test --------
Next activation in  5 seconds
```

Output after full countdown:

```
-------- test --------
2022/18/06 21:21
```

It's a pretty archaic method (at least I imagine it is), so I brought this question for improvements and professionalization of the method.

Comment: `ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'; sys.stdout.write(ERASE_LINE)` see [ANSI Escape Sequences](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#ansi-escape-sequences).

Comment: Hi @JosefZ this method generate a multiple blank space before new print: ```.                          -------- test --------``` (I had to add a dot ```.``` at the beginning because the formatting ignores whitespace at the beginning)

Comment: `sys.stdout.write('\r' + ERASE_LINE)` or `sys.stdout.write(ERASE_LINE + '\r')`. There are no spaces at the erased line however the cursor position does not change by `ERASE_LINE` itself.

Comment: Perfect, I understood the process indicated by you, thank's @JosefZ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI escape sequences are not necessary, and the so-called archaic method of using a carriage return is preferred.

Avoid mixing `sys.stdout` with `print`; prefer the latter. This offers a `flush` kwarg to be used instead of `sys.stdout.flush()`.

For the purposes of demonstration it's best if you include a seconds-field in your timestamp.

Think about the assumptions of `print()`. It has a default ending character of a linefeed. A more uniform approach to printing uses either a terminating linefeed or a terminating carriage return, not a prefix carriage return. During the sleeping period, the carriage return will have the cursor sitting at the beginning of the line, ready to overwrite with either another progress banner or real output.

### Suggested

```py
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime


def main():
    progress_len = 0

    while True:
        print(
            f'{"-------- test --------":{progress_len}}\n'
            f'{datetime.now():%Y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S}'
        )

        for remaining in range(5, 0, -1):
            txt_value = f'Next activation in {remaining:2d} seconds'
            progress_len = len(txt_value)
            print(txt_value, end='\r', flush=True)
            sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```